# send() function in C how to handle if not all bytes are sent?

Tags: c, sockets

I need to send data across to the socket, basically transferring a file ,

According to send() function docs, it says,

```
If no error occurs, send returns the total number of bytes sent, which can be less than the number requested to be sent in the len parameter. Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned,
```

The line that I am worried about is, the return value may be less than requested value.
Because I am reading from a file and writing to a socket, because it may not send all the bytes, I guess I would have to retry if the full buffer was not sent ? in which case I guess I would have to somehow advance the pointer on the same buffer by bytes read and send it again ??

I just want know if that's the way about it ? or is there a much clever way to it, so that all the requested data gets sent without me having to worry about when not all data was sent ?

Thanks,

Comment: Both sender & receiver processes should handle the case when the data has been split in chunks by the TCP/IP implementations. So you may need to do several `send` and `recv` and you should care about the results.

Comment: You will find that this situation never actually arises in blocking mode, regardless of what the documentation says. `send()` blocks until all the data has been transferred into the socket send buffer.

Comment: @EJP It _can_ arise in blocking mode though. For example, if a signal handler interrupts a `send()` that has transmitted some of the data, but not all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you have to advance the buffer pointer and repeat the `send` call until either the entire buffer is consumed or you get a hard error.  The standard idiom looks something like this:

```
int
send_all(int socket, const void *buffer, size_t length, int flags)
{
    ssize_t n;
    const char *p = buffer;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        n = send(socket, p, length, flags);
        if (n <= 0)
            return -1;
        p += n;
        length -= n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you are sending datagrams whose boundaries matter (e.g. UDP) you *cannot use this technique*; you have to treat a short send as a failure.

Answer (score 7):

You could try something like:

```
int ret, bytes = 0;
while (bytes < buflen) {
    ret = send(sock_fd, buf+bytes, buflen-bytes, flags);
    //check for errors
    if (ret == -1) {
        // handle error
    }
    bytes+=ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you do have to worry about the value returned by `send` (or `write` and so on). There is no extremely clever way around it, but there are a few functions written by the excellent Richard Stevens, namely `readn` and `writen`.

[This article on informit](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169505&seqNum=9) seems to have a version of these functions.